# Azure Media Service Submit JobInputHttp from a private blob storage container

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-media-services

I want to submit a **JobInputHttp** from a private azure blob storage container but I keep getting an **access denied error** when Media Services tries to download the file.

My Azure Media Service account has a **User Manage Identity** which I have also assigned to the private blob storage account.

[image: Same User Assigned Manage Identity for both Azure-Media-Service And StorageACC]

The whole thing works properly when I add a SAS key to the private blob storage URL when submitting the Job but I would like to avoid doing that.

Is this supposed to work or do I always need to pass a SAS key in the JobInputHttp Url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is by design. The `JobInputHttp` is not 'aware' of Azure Storage as a special type of HTTP server. The `JobInputHttp` is meant to work with *any* web server—and, therefore, the HTTP URL must be public.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also please verify if the storage account is associated with managed identity in the “storage accounts” menu(in media services extension).

Comment: Yes, I have also associated the second / private storage account to media service but still getting "The files are not accessible"